# How do I adjust timeout on the "readLines(url(),...)" function in R

Tags: r, url, web

I am reading json data from a slow site using the "R" language with commands of the form:

```
my_raw_text <- readLines(url(myurl),...)
```

the default timeout, found using "getOption("timeout")" is 60 seconds.

Can you tell me the "R" command to bump this up to ~5 minutes?

I tried putting "timemout=5*60" into the url, but it isn't accepted.  There is something in socketConnection, but I'm not sure how to set that up quickly and well for urls.  I tried looking for a "setOption" command but did not see it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `options(timeout = 5*60)`?

Comment: I'm going to try it and see how well it works.  
oldoptions <- getOption(...); options(...); runmycode(); options(oldoptions)

Comment: Could you provide the URL you are trying to read?